# How to soloved the Twilio error number 21408

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I want to send SMS to Belgium but there is an error regarding the sending here is the error number: Error 21408
Please I want a quick solution for this problem thank you

I tried to configure the countries to which my project allows messaging content to be sent but this link does not work more: https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/settings/geo-permissions

Answer (score 0):

This links seems to be dead, thanks for pointing that out. The right URL is, depending on your region, https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/sms/settings/geo-permissions. You can also navigate there from the side menu in the [Twilio Console](https://console.twilio.com/):

[image: Nav Path to Geo Permissions]

PS: I'll let the team know there is a broken link they can hopefully fix.